# Como resolver "Limpe sua arvore de trabalho"?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Eu e a equipe que estou, trabalhamos com GIT + Visual Studio Code...
Quando mexemos no mesmo arquivo, quando vamos fazer comitar/puxar os arquivos, acontece o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existe alguma forma de resolver isso, porque hoje nos colocamos as alterações locais num bloco de notas, fazemos o push, fazemos as modificações novamente e ai comitamos o local...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consigo lhe ajudar a resolver isso utilizando o terminal:

1. Execute `git stash` para guardar suas alterações atuais
2. Execute a operação que deseja (`pull` por exemplo)
3. Execute `git stash pop` para tirar suas alterações da pilha de stashes

Depois disso você pode ter de realizar merges entre os arquivos do stash e a nova codebase baixada.

Você também pode dar nome aos stashes através do comando `git stash save "Minha mensagem de identificação para o stash"`

A listagem de stashes pode ser feita através do comando `git stash list`

Comment: Quando acontecer de novo, vamos tentar fazer desta forma, muitissimo obrigado pela resposta

Comment: Testamos aqui e funcionou :)

Comment: De nada, é um prazer ajudar :)